# Проблемы в работе функции SHFileOperation при копировании папки

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Проблемы в работе функции SHFileOperation. Произвожу с помощью нее копировании папки, но функция завершается с кодом ошибки 87 или 2. Имеется следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    std::string directionNames = argv[1];

    std::string sourceDir = directionNames + "\\*\0\0";
    std::string targetDir = directionNames + "_delComments";

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT   SHF;

    SHF.hwnd = 0;
    SHF.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    SHF.pFrom = sourceDir.c_str();
    SHF.pTo = targetDir.c_str();
    SHF.fFlags = 512;
    SHF.hNameMappings = 0;
    SHF.lpszProgressTitle = 0;

    int result = SHFileOperation(&SHF);

    if (result != 0)
        if (SHF.fAnyOperationsAborted)
            std::cout << "Выполнение операции прервано пользователем\n";
        else std::cout << "Ошибка выполнения операции\n";
    else std::cout << "Операция успешно завершена\n";

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Также наблюдается ситуация, когда 1 раз за 15-20 запусков  копирование выполняется успешно. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: msdn вам не помог? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx там описаны коды ошибок.

Comment: @nick_n_a Да я читал документаци ошибка 87:  DE_SRC_IS_DVD 0x87 The source is a read-only DVD, possibly unformatted, Но причину возникновения и как ее исправить не понимаю

Comment: @MaxU, возможно Вы путаете код ошибки 0x87 с кодом 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER). Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4568158/6171622)

Comment: @Embedder Да, вы правы, я перепутал)  Но решение исправления ошибки  87 представленное там путем добавления     `ZeroMemory(&SHF, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCT));`  не принесло результатов

Comment: Я бы для такой программы не мучался бы с string а сделал бы массив char, и поставил бы strcpy, strcpy, strcat, strcat и всё (что б всё было ASCIIZ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка 2 - `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (файл не найден), ошибка 86 - `ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD` (The specified network password is not correct - указанный сетевой пароль неверен). Очень подозрительные ошибки. Если Вы говорите, что при одних и тех же параметрах код иногда работает, то, учитывая эти ошибки, возникает подозрение, что где-то что-то не инициализировано и иногда "мусор" в памяти складывается так, как нам нужно. Поскольку ошибка возникает при вызове `SHFileOperation`, то проблему следует искать в инициализации её аргумента.

Далее читаем [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb759795(v=vs.85).aspx). В примечании видим:

> You must ensure that the source and destination paths are double-null terminated.

Перевод:

> Вы должны убедиться, что пути источника и назначения завершаются двумя нулевыми символами.

Но переменная `targetDir` в вашем коде является обычной строкой `std::string` и преобразование её в *C*-строку даст только один завершающий ноль. Поэтому следует недостающий ноль добавить:

```
target_dir += '\0'.
```

---

***UPDATE***

Моё вышеприведённое умозаключение было неверным, хотя направление оказалось правильным. Дело в том, что при конкатенации строк типа `std::string` для второй строки вызовется конструктор класса `std::string`, который получит в качестве аргумента обычную строку *C*, которую прочитает до ***первого*** нулевого символа, т.е. дополнительный нулевой символ будет проигнорирован. Чтобы избежать этого, дополнительный нулевой символ в конце строки нужно добавлять отдельно:

```
std::string sourceDir = directionNames + "\\";
sourceDir.push_back('\0');
std::string targetDir = directionNames + "_delComments\\";
targetDir.push_back('\0');
```

С вышеприведённым кодом работает.

Comment: Добавления нуля не помогло исправить ситуацию, и ошибка не 86 всплывает а 87, которая гласит: DE_SRC_IS_DVD 0x87 The source is a read-only DVD, possibly unformatted,   Не понимаю суть возникновения данной ошибки и как с ней боротся

Comment: А как возникает ошибка? Пользователь может не верно том указать? Или там русскую C: поставить вместо английской C:? Может вам логировать аргументы при ошибке?

Comment: Вы же всётаки никак не проверяете валидность входных параметров. Попробуйте FindFirstFile функцию - что она вам скажет (что б проверить существование папки)? Попробуйте как-то проверить валидность входных параметров. Как-то можно CreateFile проверить что это папка, но мне FindFirstFile  проще. Поставьте цикл на 2 шага - если без ошибок - break; если с ошибкой - дебаггер (ф-ция DebugBreak например).

Comment: @nick_n_a Я передаю папку через командную строку путем переноса нужной папки на exe-шник программы, В итоге создается пустая копия папки , а все вложения теряются. Иногда как я говорил проходит все успешно и создается копия со всеми вложениями, но очень редко

Comment: Что вы делаете 1. c пробелами, если в имени папки есть пробелы? 2. Попробуйте поставить маску `*.*` вместо `*`  Винда почему-то плохо воспринимает одну *.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я тестирую на папках без пробелов, если в имени папке есть пробелы то происходит тоже самое создается копия без вложений и ошибка 87 , замена одной звездочки также не помогло

Comment: @MaxU Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Повторюсь: 1. Поставьте логирование ошибок. 2. Обверните циклом на 2 шага, и поставьте break если без ошибок точку останова при ошибке, что б отладить ошибку. 3 (новое) поставьте MessageBox параметров  SHF.pFrom и  SHF.pTo. 4. Поставьте таки `SHFILEOPSTRUCT   SHF={0,};` как советуют в ссылках.

Comment: @kff Да все заработало, спасибо  за помощь

Comment: @nick_n_a все разъяснилось, код не работал из-за игнорирования второго нуля и требования добавления его отдельно, Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующий код

```
std::wstring new_sf = source_folder + L"\\*";
WCHAR sf[MAX_PATH + 1];
WCHAR tf[MAX_PATH + 1];

wcscpy_s(sf, MAX_PATH, new_sf.c_str());
wcscpy_s(tf, MAX_PATH, target_folder.c_str());

sf[lstrlenW(sf) + 1] = 0;
tf[lstrlenW(tf) + 1] = 0;

SHFILEOPSTRUCTW s = { 0 };
s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
s.pTo = tf;
s.pFrom = sf;
s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NO_UI;
int res = SHFileOperationW(&s);
```